# Can one Swift typealias be constrained to another in a protocol definition? If not, how else can I achieve something like component registration?

Tags: swift, typedef, type-alias

I am writing a small inversion of control container for my own little framework in swift (mainly so I can learn more) and I have stumbled across a problem - well, several problems of which this is just the latest.

I had hoped that swift would be flexible enough for me to port the core patterns of `Castle.Core` in C#. My first disappointment was in the weak reflection capabilities provided by Apple, which led me to do this ugliness...

```
public protocol ISupportInjection {

}

public protocol IConstructorArguments {

    func toArgumentsDictionary() -> [String:AnyObject?]

}

public protocol ISupportConstructorInjection: ISupportInjection {

    init(parameters:IConstructorArguments)

}
```

...the idea being that someday (soon) I could deal with it and remove any reference to these constraints in my services/components.

Now I want to write `IIocRegistration` with two `typealias`: one for the `TService` and the other for the `TComponent`, ideally where `TService` is a `protocol` and `TComponent` is a concrete `struct` or `class` that implements `TService`:

```
public protocol IIocRegistration {

    typealias TService: Any
    typealias TComponent: TService, ISupportConstructorInjection

}
```

But it seems that `TComponent: TService` is totally invalid according to the compiler, which says:

> Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type '`Self`.TService'

So I am wondering how to make a `typealias` derive another `typealias` if it possible.

Comment: Please don't port C# things (like this I or T prefix) over to Swift where it wouldn't provide any meaning to any Swift developers (unless they are really C# devs who are now writing Swift) and would just serve as a point for this question endlessly "Why is there a T here?"  "What's this I doing?" We don't abbreviate things in Cocoa/CocoaTouch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all what `typealias` do inside a swift protocol is not to define a type alias. The keyword `typealias` inside swift protocol is used to define `associated type` about which you can check out the swift programming book.

Back to your situation the possible solution I can come up with is move the `typealias` outside protocol like such

```
public typealias TService = Any

public struct component: TService, ISupportConstructorInjection {
    public init(parameters: IConstructorArguments) {
        //
    }
}

public typealias TComponent = component

public protocol IIocRegistration {
    var service: TService {get set}
    var component: TComponent {get set}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late acceptance, your answer was fine but I was hoping it was not the best available :)